# Change wrap of TMENU when active menu item has a submenu

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to change the `wrap` of a `TMENU` if the current active menu item has a submenu (`ACTIFSUB`).

Below is a excerpt of my typoscript:

```
lib.navigation = HMENU
lib.navigation {

1 = TMENU
1 {

    wrap = <ul class="m-navigation-list">|</ul>

    # if the current active menu item has a submenu, change the wrap to this:
    # wrap = <ul class="m-navigation-list m-navigation-list--parent">|</ul>

    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="m-navigation-item m-navigation-link--parent m-navigation-link--ladder">|</li>

        # overwrite the wrap of the TMENU?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful as if you enable expAll, submenus will be always printed and as consequence override will be always used.

Here is working example:

```
lib.navigation = HMENU
lib.navigation {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    wrap.override = <ul class="override">|</ul>
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 0
        NO.allWrap = <li> | </li>
        ACT = 1
        ACT.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB {
             allWrap= <li class="sub">|</li>
             before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
             before.cObject.actsubmenu = TEXT
             before.cObject.actsubmenu.value = 1
        }
    }
    wrap.override.if.isTrue.data = REGISTER:actsubmenu
}
```

Comment: wow, amazing! Thanks! The `REGISTER` thing did the trick! I had one problem though: my active menu point would (`ACTIFSUB`) not print the link text. But I could fix it by using `before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER` like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17569034/723769

Comment: Right, I didn't test and didn't think of that cObject would override default text.. I'll update the code above